# integer solutions for a system of two composite inequalities

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, combinations

Let $a,b,c,d,m_1, n_1, m_2, n_2$ are all integers with $ad-bc \ne 0$. I am trying to list all integer solutions for the following system
\begin{equation}
m_1 \leq ax+by \leq n_1,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
m_2 \leq cx+dy \leq n_2.
\end{equation}

I can see that the solution is the interior region (plus the boundary) of the parallelogram whose sides are represented by the lines:
$m_1 = ax+by$, $ax+by = n_1$ (opposite sides) and
$m_2 = cx+dy $, $\leq cx+dy = n_2$ (opposite sides.)

I can also find the coordinates the four vertices for the parallelogram.
But not sure how to list all integer solutions in a mathematical way.

Comment: What do you mean, "list them in a mathematical way?" For example, you could describe the set of solutions as $\{(x,y)\mid x,y\in \mathbb Z, m_1\le ax+by\le n_1,m_2\le cx+dy\le n_2\}$, but that is not helpful. On the other hand, one could give a compute program which lists all integer pairs, given $a,b,c,d,m_{1,2},n_{1,2}$. But I do not think you are going to find a nice "formula" to list out all of the solutions.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, you are right. Thank you!